# How to make an html Textarea Scroll to end?

Tags: html, textarea

I've defined an html textarea like this:

```
<TEXTAREA style='width:100%' ROWS=15 readonly='readonly'>
```

Is there any parameter where I can defined that I want to see the scroll at the end of the textarea?

I know I could provide an id and make it scroll to the end with jquery/javascript but isn't it there a simpler way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you mean the inner scroll bar of the textarea its not possible without javascript.

also the synthax of your textarea is really strange. you mix up upper with lowercase.. use singlequotes or no quotes for attributes instead of doublequotes and hopefully your not missing the closing  tag

Comment: Thanks @ggzone, it was like I suspected. I close the tag after I write the content. The mix ups are really wicked, I'm gonna change it then :)